# Hypothesis testing on a binomial probability ratio

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

A colleague has asked me to assess the data analytic approach taken by one of his students for a previous experiment. If you want to skip the details of the experimental design skip down to *Data analysis Part 2* and *My questions* below.

**Experimental design.**
In its simplest form, the experiment consists of a single subject completing a single session of 100 trials. In each session, the subject is first presented with a pre-testing set of stimuli that conform to a particular pattern. For the subsequent 100 trials, the subject is then presented with more stimuli and is asked (yes/no) whether they are consistent with the pre-test pattern. Although the stimuli were generated according to a fixed rule, the subject is not given the rule and therefore must infer and apply a rule based upon the observed pre-test pattern.

**Hypotheses.** The student has two goals for statistical analysis. The first is the obvious hypothesis test of whether the subject's performance is consistent with the actual stimuli-generating rule. The second set of hypotheses concern whether the subject's performance is also consistent with a variety of other possible rules hypothesized a priori by the experimenter. In particular, the student wants to know what the likelihoods of other possible rules are relative to the most likely rule for the subject.

**Data analysis**.

*Part 1.*
The subject's data are treated as a random sample from a binomial process. The student assumed a 5% performance error rate for the subject, such that the probability of success (correct yes/no answer) for each trial is $θ = 0.95$.

For the first hypothesis, the student conducted a log-likelihood ratio test comparing the subject's observed performance ($\hat{θ}$) to the assumed population parameter ($θ$). The subject answered correctly on 93% ($k=93$) of the trials ($n=100$). The log-likelihood ratio is therefore:

$$2[k\ln\frac{\hat{θ}}{θ}+(n-k)\ln\bigg(\frac{1-\hat{θ}}{1-θ}\bigg)]=2[93\ln\frac{0.93}{0.95}+(7)\ln\bigg(\frac{0.07}{0.05}\bigg)]=0.753$$

The student cannot reject the null hypothesis ($H_0:\hat{θ}=θ)$ for $\alpha=0.05$ and therefore concludes that the subject's performance is consistent with the stimulus generating rule. This approach seems appropriate to me, although it may be questionable to assume each trial is *i.i.d.* within the session for a single subject. Nonetheless, I'm more concerned with the student's approach for the second set of hypotheses.

*Part 2.* The student is now interested in asking, given the subject's performance, what is the likelihood that the subject's performance is also consistent with a set of other possible rules? To answer this question, the student again fixes the population parameter, reflecting his expectation that the probability of answering correctly *relative to any of the hypothesized rules* is constant. That is to say, even if the stimulus set was generated according to rule *A*, the subject answering according to rule *B* is just as likely to select yes for any trials consistent with *B* (and vice versa).

In order to compare the rules, the student therefore had to recalculate the subject's $k$ for every hypothesized rule. For example, $k=20$ for rule *B* if the subject's performance on 20/100 trials generated with rule *A* was also consistent with *B*. Thus, the student generated a 'new' dataset for every rule, albeit assuming each to be drawn from the same underlying binomial process with distribution parameters $θ=0.95$ and $n=100$. The student then computes a ratio for every rule relative to the rule with the highest likelihood. For example, assume rule *A* has the highest success rate at $k=93$ and $k=89$ for rule B. The student would then calculate what he believed to be a relative likelihood ratio:

$$\exp([\ln\binom{100}{89}+(89)\ln(0.95)+(11)\ln(0.05)])-  \\
\qquad\quad\;[\ln\binom{100}{93}+(93)\ln(0.95)+(7)\ln(0.05)]=0.068$$

**My questions**. Given that the population parameters are held constant, this is not a relative likelihood ratio but rather a probability ratio for $Pr(X=89)/Pr(X=93)$. Moreover, by holding the population parameters constant, my thinking is that there are zero degrees of freedom for the comparison. This would make the probability ratio meaningless for hypothesis testing with the $\chi^2$ distribution, as is done with the log-likelihood ratio.

Is my thinking here correct? If so, are there heuristic criteria or alternative approaches by which the magnitude of such a probability ratio could be interpreted? I've already thought of using simple $\chi^2$ goodness-of-fit or Fisher's exact tests for observed vs. expected yes/no responses, which would avoid these issues entirely and not require the 'generation' of new $k$ for every rule. Any other possible solutions would also be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.